# Array remove all elements with value input by user

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have the following arrays, what's the algorithm to remove all element which is input by user?

```
eg.int arr[size]={12,10,7,43,12,12,26,83};
```

if i want to delete 12 
so the output should look like :

```
{10,7,43,26,83}
```

Comment: You can't resize a VLA.

Comment: What do you mean with "remove"?

Comment: As such one cannot remove elements from an array but one can replace existing elements. One approach could be to have a temporary array, copy all elements except the one to  be deleted from the original array. And then copy back the temporary array to the original array.

Comment: @Zinov Apart from the title, that question is pretty messy. Not a good canonical duplicate, in my opinion.

Comment: Anyway, if you need to frequently add/delete items, you would use a linked list instead of an array. That is why linked lists exist.

Comment: Please see the SomeProgrammerDude answer , it will give you more insight and without testing never mark answer as best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the most straightforward solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  const int size = 8;
  int arr[size] = { 12, 10, 7, 43, 12, 12, 26, 83 };
  int input;
  int result_size = 0;
  scanf("%d", &input);

  // Find out size of new array
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (arr[i] != input)
    {
      result_size++;
    }
  }

  // Create new array
  int *result = (int*)malloc(result_size * sizeof(int));
  if (!result)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  // Fill new array
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
  {
    if (arr[i] != input)
    {
      result[j++] = arr[i];
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < result_size; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", result[i]);
  }

  free(result);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ....but the question is tagged [tag:c] not [tag:c++]....

Comment: Thank you, I used 'new' by habit. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you *can't* remove elements from an array. An array have a fixed size, once it is set it can not be changed.

Possible solutions are to use a special value to mark "empty" elements in the array. Or to copy the non-removed data to another array. Or to keep track of the current "size" (number of "active" elements) of the array and move the elements around so they are always at the "front" of the array.